# Unexpected behaviour of `with-handlers` in typed Racket

Tags: exception, error-handling, racket, typed-racket

I am trying to handle certain kinds of errors in typed Racket. The following code works as expected in both typed and untyped Racket

```
(with-handlers
    ([exn:fail:contract:divide-by-zero?
      (lambda (e)
        (raise e))])
    (let ([x 0]
          [y 1])
      (display (/ y x))))
```

resulting in the error message

```
/: division by zero
```

A slight elaboration works in untyped Racket:

```
(with-handlers
    ([exn:fail:contract:divide-by-zero?
      (lambda (e)
        (displayln "oops!")
        (raise e))])
    (let ([x 0]
          [y 1])
      (display (/ y x))))
```

```
oops!
/: division by zero
```

But gives the following error message in typed Racket:

```
Type Checker: No function domains matched in function application:
Domains: (U (Rec flat (U (Immutable-HashTable flat flat) (Immutable-Vectorof flat) (Pairof flat flat) Boolean Bytes Char Complex Keyword Null String Symbol)) exn) Any 
         (U (Rec flat (U (Immutable-HashTable flat flat) (Immutable-Vectorof flat) (Pairof flat flat) Boolean Bytes Char Complex Keyword Null String Symbol)) exn) 
Arguments: Any
 in: (raise e)
```

Can someone explain what is going on here, or suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in normal Racket, the first argument to [`raise`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._raise%29%29) can be any value, for some reason in Typed Racket it's limited to a list of specific types, including the `exn` hierarchy of structures.

I've found you almost always have to explicitly specify the types of arguments to functions; Typed Racket typically doesn't infer them and gives them the generic `Any` type. Thus, to satisfy `raise`'s type:

```
#lang typed/racket/base

(with-handlers
    ([exn:fail:contract:divide-by-zero?
      (lambda ([e : exn]) ; The type of a struct is usually the name of the struct
        (displayln "oops!")
        (raise e))])
    (let ([x 0]
          [y 1])
      (display (/ y x))))
```

Comment: The interesting bit is why your first example works in TR; I suspect expressions like `(lambda (x) (f x))` are turned into `f` before type checking is done, and the more complicated one isn't inlined like that.

Comment: Thanks! In my original question I forget to mention that I had also tried `lambda ([e : Any])` which gave the same results as `lambda (e)` in TR. So you also answered a question which I did not ask :)